# How movable are iOS debug symbols in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debug-symbols

I'm using QuincyKit to analyse crash dumps from my iOS apps. QuincyKit's symbolication script is capable of handling both my code and system code - as long as the debug symbols for the relevant version of iOS are present on the machine.

Said symbols reside under `(Home)/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport`. Question - did anyone ever try to move those folders from one machine with Xcode to another?

I could use some 7.0.x symbols; chances of getting a device with that version are practically nil by now.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the source of `symbolicatecrash.pl` that you use for symbolication.

It searches the iOS system symbols in the following paths:

```
/System/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/*.platform/DeviceSupport/
```

These paths are hardcoded and may change with every update of the script (as it is part of Xcode).

Comment: The script that I's using came with QuincyKit; it's not Xcode's original. Anyways, the real question is - is there any chance for downloading those symbols off the 'Net as opposed to pulling them from devices?

Comment: The script is identical and only includes a few bug fixes. No, there is no way to download them somewhere.